# Is Hazelcast Clustering recommended for a WSO2 Active-Active Deployment?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, hazelcast

I have an Active-Active Deployment of WSO2 API Manager. I don't know if I should enable Hazelcast Clustering, because:

A) On one hand, in the [link of official documentation that I followed to deploy](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Configuring+an+Active-Active+Deployment), Hazelcast doesn't appear.

B) On the other hand, this [link of official documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Working+with+Hazelcast+Clustering#WorkingwithHazelcastClustering-EnablingHazelcastclustering) says that backend throttling limits will not be shared across the cluster when Hazelcast clustering is disabled (and I of course want that backend throttling limits are shared across the cluster!). But that link is under section "Distributed Deployment", and I haven't a "Distributed Deployment". As I said, I have a "Active-Active Deployment", so I don't know if I should follow that link and install Hazelcast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need backend throttling, then you have to enable clustering in the nodes. Although it is mentioned under distributed deployment, for Active-Active deployment also needs clustering if you require backend service throttling.

The idea here is that two nodes serve the requests while they are in a cluster and enable backend service throttling.

Comment: Ok, maybe a reference of Hazelcast telling this should be added to the official documentation of Configuring an Active-Active Deployment.

Answer (score 0):

> if I should follow that link and install Hazelcast

You don't need to install anything, just enable the clustering and setup the IP addresses if wka membership scheme is used (please not many cloud providers or native docker don't support multicast)

The hazelcast cluster is used to broadcast the token invalidation messages and throttling limits. You don't need to enable the cluster at all, but then you may miss the messages between nodes.

Comment: I should say "enable" instead of "install", OK. But the point is, that even in an active-active deployment I should enable Hazelcast clustering to throttling limits work as expected. Right?

Comment: ´enable Hazelcast clustering to throttling limits work as expected´ - affirmative. Otherwise one node wouldn't know that another one reached the throttling limit (or that a token has been revoked)